# Two DataSet within single StoredProcedure of MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am using Mysql database. In which I have to create a stored procedure with two select statements from which I want to return two different datasets.
But when I create stored procedure, it takes only first select statement. My procedure is as below,

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`$$
CREATE  PROCEDURE `test`()
SELECT * FROM `ps.pass`$$
SELECT * FROM `ps.pass_type`$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But after creating second statement `ps.pass_type`, it's not adding into the stored procedure. Any suggessions are most welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are ending the procedure using the delimiter after the first select and you should do it at the end.

Here is an example

```
mysql> select * from clients ;
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | james |
|    2 | jill  |
+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from timesheets ;
+-----------+-------+----------+
| client_id | hours | category |
+-----------+-------+----------+
|         1 |  1.50 | onsite   |
|         1 |  1.50 | onsite   |
|         1 |  1.00 | remote   |
|         2 |  1.50 | remote   |
+-----------+-------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now lets create a procedure like yours

```
delimiter //

create procedure test_case()
begin
 select * from clients ;
 select * from timesheets ;
end;//

delimiter ;
```

In mysql once its created lets call the procedure

```
mysql> call test_case();
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | james |
|    2 | jill  |
+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+-----------+-------+----------+
| client_id | hours | category |
+-----------+-------+----------+
|         1 |  1.50 | onsite   |
|         1 |  1.50 | onsite   |
|         1 |  1.00 | remote   |
|         2 |  1.50 | remote   |
+-----------+-------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```